# mmv not rename files .JPG to .jpg

Tags: bash, ubuntu, batch-rename

I have many files like this:

```
13040-3BLK1.JPG  13040-3NAV11.JPG  13040-50NAV11.JPG  13040-60NAV11.JPG  13040-LNAV1.JPG  13040-MDGR1.JPG  15026-3PNK1.JPG  94010-4NAV1.JPG    KH00010-LSLV1.JPG  KH00030-SWHT1.JPG 
13040-3NAV1.JPG  13040-50NAV1.JPG  13040-60NAV1.JPG   13040-LBLK1.JPG    13040-MBLK1.JPG  13100-MNAV1.JPG  15140_3NAV1.JPG  KH00010-LNAV1.JPG  KH00010-MRBL1.JPG  MU00070-LGOL1.JPG
```

I want to change the .JPG files into .jpg files (uppercase to lowercase). I run this command to do that:

```
mmv '*.JPG' '#1.jpg'
```

But nothing changes. However when I run this command:

```
mmv -n '*.JPG' '#1.jpg'
```

It displays the right changes:

```
13040-3BLK1.JPG -> 13040-3BLK1.jpg
13040-3NAV1.JPG -> 13040-3NAV1.jpg
13040-3NAV11.JPG -> 13040-3NAV11.jpg
13040-50NAV1.JPG -> 13040-50NAV1.jpg
13040-50NAV11.JPG -> 13040-50NAV11.jpg
13040-60NAV1.JPG -> 13040-60NAV1.jpg
13040-60NAV11.JPG -> 13040-60NAV11.jpg
13040-LBLK1.JPG -> 13040-LBLK1.jpg
13040-LNAV1.JPG -> 13040-LNAV1.jpg
13040-MBLK1.JPG -> 13040-MBLK1.jpg
13040-MDGR1.JPG -> 13040-MDGR1.jpg
13100-MNAV1.JPG -> 13100-MNAV1.jpg
15026-3PNK1.JPG -> 15026-3PNK1.jpg
15140_3NAV1.JPG -> 15140_3NAV1.jpg
94010-4NAV1.JPG -> 94010-4NAV1.jpg
KH00010-LNAV1.JPG -> KH00010-LNAV1.jpg
KH00010-LSLV1.JPG -> KH00010-LSLV1.jpg
KH00010-MRBL1.JPG -> KH00010-MRBL1.jpg
KH00030-SWHT1.JPG -> KH00030-SWHT1.jpg
MU00070-LGOL1.JPG -> MU00070-LGOL1.jpg
```

Why the files are not renamed ? And how can I rename them? With or without the package mmv.

Comment: without `mmv`: `for file in *.JPG ; do mv "${file}" "${file%.JPG}.jpg"; done`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul if directory contain no `.JPG`, this will execute `mv *.JPG *.jpg`

Comment: @LéaGris, thank you, in this case `No such file or directory` can be avoided using `shopt -s nullglob` or `shopt -s globfail` or `for file in *.JPG ; do [[ -e $file ]] && mv "${file}" "${file%.JPG}.jpg"; done`

Comment: My bash is an emulation on a windows laptop, which is technically not case sensitive. I've had this problem - I fixed it with a two-step workaround where I changed each filename to something *else*, then changed it to what I wanted. It retained the case I assigned, as long as the only difference was NOT the case of the letters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a Windows case-insensitivity issue - 
Two-step loop?

```
for f in *.JPG
do mv "$f" tmp
   mv tmp "${f%.JPG}.jpg"
done
```

Comment: Yes this is on the new Windows Terminal and in fact this is the problem.